# AppCompat & Support library version for SDK Platform 26

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I have already installed Android SDK Platform 26, Android SDK Tools 26.0.2

[image]

This is my app level `build.gradle` file.

**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        ...
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I can't sync the gradle. I am getting these errors:

```
Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2
Error:(27, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2
```

Are the `appcompat` and `support` library versions are wrong?

How can I solve this issue? Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are two things to it

**First**

[This](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html) is the page that announces recent releases of the support library, and I don't see 26.0.2 version. The latest is 26.0.0-beta2 and
**Note that 26.0.0-beta2 is a pre-release version**

**Second**

Make sure you have google's maven repository included in you project's gradle file. Something like :

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The first point is right. But in my Android Studio's SDK Manager is showing SDK build tools version 26.0.2. After installing it's showing revision 26.0.2. That's why this problem has occurred.

Comment: In Gradle 4.1 you can write `google()` instead of `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }`. (Actually it's `https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/` but that's equivalent.)

Answer (score -2):

appcompat version must to match with SdkVersion.
Try this one

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

Comment: Please add more context to your answer to address how your answer solves the problems asked in the question.